# Database-related events in MS Access VSTO Add-In

Tags: ms-access, vsto

Is it possible to intercept database-related events using Access VSTO Add-In? I'm interested in "Open Database" and "Close Database" events in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Since Access does not have an open database event, nor does it have a close database event, then then nothing much here can be gained of any use by adopting VSTO. (you don’t get or gain any new events that don’t exist in the first place).

In fact, in most cases, the simplest approach is to build a COM object in Visual Studio and use that in Access.

Using VSTO with Access does not really offer much of anything I can think of use wise that is better than creating a .net COM object for consumption by Access.

As a result, in most cases it’s usually better to do things the other way around – simply have Access application use/consume a .net COM object.